# SQL Server : copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

I want to update `Table2` names with names from `Table1` with matching Ids

I have around 100 rows in each table.

Here is my sample tables.

**Table1**

- ID
- Name

**Table2**

- ID
- Name

Sample data

**Table1**

```
    ID |Name
    --------
     1 |abc
     2 |bcd
```

**Table2**

```
    ID |Name
    --------
     1 |xyz
     2 |OOS
```

Expected result

**Table2**

```
    ID |Name
    --------        
     1 |abc
     2 |bcd
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move SQL data from one table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` of the two tables on the `id` field:

```
update t2
set t2.name = t1.name
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1
  on t2.id = t1.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a109/2)