# Copy down a value from a parent tuple in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for an elegant way to copy down a value from a parent tuple to a child.  I need it to be copied as it can change independently of the parent value, but that is the baseline to start.

Here is a simplified version of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentValue VARCHAR(128)
);


CREATE TABLE Child (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Parent(Id),
    ChildValue VARCHAR(128)
);
```

Now what I am looking to do is this:

```
   UPDATE Child
   SET ChildValue = Parent.ParentValue
   WHERE TRUE
```

Does that makes sense?  I have a looping way, but it does not seem efficient for the multitude of records I plan on running it for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : copy data from one table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077746/sql-server-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the proprietary `UPDATE FROM` syntax

```
UPDATE Child
SET ChildValue = ParentValue
FROM Child
JOIN Parent ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId;
```

or the standard SQL `MERGE` syntax as you are on 2008

```
MERGE INTO Child
   USING Parent
      ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET ChildValue = ParentValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

A portable way to write the query is using a correlated subquery in the `set` clause:

```
update child
    set childValue = (select ParentValue from Parent where Parent.ParentId = Child.ParentId)
```

I don't know if you consider this elegant, though.