# limiting amount of database queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Before reading my question please keep in mind the following is work im doing on a personal project to learn / broaden my php / mysql skills, thus im still very much a rookie as I am sure is evident in my coding which follows. However any tips / helps appreciated

**What my app does**

My site allows users to guess what will the outcome be of a sporting match, after the match has finished results are uploaded and winning members gets rewarded "credits"

**Psuedo Code for verifying winners**

1. Upload a result of an event / sports match
2. Move old event from `activeEvents` table to `expiredEvents` table
3. Now delete event data from `activeEvents` table
4. Check who guessed the correct match result in `picks table` with
   uploaded data in step 1
5. Insert winning members who guessed correctly into `winners` table
6. Move old pick data to `expiredPicks` table
7. Delete data moved to `expiredPicks` table from `activePicks` table

**My Problem**

For each step described above Im doing a new query to database, this not only leads to slow response times but just seems down right inefficient, I am looking for some suggestions on how I can keep same functionality but improve my code

```
if(isset($_POST['resultBtn'])){
    //STEP 1:----GET GAME INFO
    foreach($_POST['winner'] as $id =>$winner){
        $winScore = $_POST['score'][$id];
        $teamsel[] = $winner ;
        $team1 = $_POST['team1'][$id];
        $team2 = $_POST['team2'][$id];
        $venue = $_POST['ven'][$id];
        $matchId = $_POST['gameId'][$id]; //match Id
        $score = $_POST['score'][$id]; //score
        $tour = $_POST['tournament'][$id];
        $round = $_POST['round'][$id];
        $event_date = $_POST['event_date'][$id];
        $gameNR = $_POST['gameNr'][$id];
        $sport=$_POST['sport'][$id];

        //STEP 2:----INSERT event info into expiredEvents
        $sql="INSERT INTO expiredEvents (event_id, sport_type, tournament, 
                        round, team1, team2, venue, event_date)
                        VALUES
                        ('$matchId', '$sport', '$tour', '$round', 
                        '$team1', '$team2','$venue','$event_date')";                                        
        mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);      

        //STEP 3:----DELETE event/match from events table
        $sql ="DELETE FROM events WHERE event_id ='$matchId'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

        //Step4: ----check for winner(s) in picks table with given data
        $sql="select * from picks where event_id = '$matchId' and
                 abs(score-$winScore) = (select min(abs(score-$winScore)) from picks 
                 where pick = '$winner');";      
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $winingMember = $row['member_nr'];
        $event = $row['event_id'];
        $pick = $row['pick'];
        $score = $row['score'];

        echo'<br />';
        echo $winingMember;
        echo'<br />';
        echo $event;
        echo'<br />';
        echo $pick;
        echo'<br />';
        echo $score;
        echo'<br />';
        echo $event_date;
        echo'<br />';

        //step5 insert winners into winners table
        $sql="INSERT INTO winners
        (member_nr,event_id, pickedTeam,pickedScore,event_date)
        VALUES
        ('$winingMember','$event','$pick','$score','$event_date')";
        mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

        }//while

        //Step 6 move old pick data to expired picks table  
        $sql="INSERT INTO expiredPicks (select * from picks WHERE event_id = '$matchId'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

        //step7: --Delete expired picks
        $sql="DELETE FROM picks where event_id='$matchId'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

    }//for each
}//isset
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another

Comment: side note, especially since you are in the process of improving your skills, its a **really good idea to stop using `mysql_` extensions.**   They are **deprecated**  (and for good reason, as they are not secure).   Look into `mysqli_` prepared statements or `PDO`.   They will also run a LOT faster for large queries..

Comment: The action queries does not seem to be bottlenecks (but the form loops through multiple records which iterates these steps for however many the webpage takes). Yet, the Step 4 query could use optimization as it uses a subquery in a where clause. And consider using status columns (with 'active' vs 'expired' values) for both events and picks which cuts down on inserts and delete actions into one-column updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought, redesign your tables and use join to be more effective with queries.

```
Table1 Sports Id - Event - Result - Date From - Date To
Table2 Users Id - Name
Table3 Picks Id - Pick - Event (FK to Sports.Id) - Name (FK to Users.Id)
Table4 Winners Id - Winner (FK to Users.ID) - Credit(?)
```

Now for Table 1 if you want to check which event is done, you just check where Result is not null and when event gets done, you can update table with a result.

This is just Initial thought, and even from now I see it would need more work, but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you its pretty clear the db design needs some major tweaking yes