# Azure Sql Cron - how to use?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have some db with data. And I need create script for migrate data from tableA to tableB. I use C# and azure web sites web-job. But I think what exists Cron for azure sql. But I can't found this. Maybe you know how to use Cron in Azure SQL.
Because I can't found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to migrate data from one table to another in Azure SQL Database. One way is to use TSQL. If this is a routine task, you may want to look into creating a stored procedure and leveraging Azure Automation to run the stored procedure on a schedule.

[This forum answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another) shows how to use TSQL to copy from one table to another.

There is a blog post which shows how to use Azure Automation with Azure SQL Database [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/).