# How to move data in the table for the same database and delete it in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a database name **test.dbo**. In the database it have two table named **Equipment** and **backup**. I want to move some data in the table **Equipment** to table **backup** and delete the data in the table **Equipment**. So, what is the query to use to do it?

I have use this query but it only move the data to table **backup** without deleting it in table **Equipment**. Moreover, if i use the query again , error show that the table name already exits.

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=5CG50749V3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * into test.dbo.[backup] from test.dbo.[Equipment] where (SerialNumber = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' or EquipmentID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' )", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move SQL data from one table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

For this, instead of the `SELECT * INTO`, use a `DELETE` statement with an `OUTPUT INTO` clause.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: can you explain more about this?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another

Comment: yeah, i have seen that. but i don't know how to write all the insert, delete and select in sql command. sorry im new to all this thing.