# Move data from tb1 to tbl2 where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to move data from column `reg` in `table1` to `reg2` in `table2`, where the `ID` of `table1 = 'ID2'` of `table2`.

basically, I need to shift car registrations from **A** to **B** as long as the person exists in **B**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

Comment: A `begin transaction`, an `insert into table2... select ...from table1 WHERE...` one `delete from table1 where ...` and a `commit` will do the work. When you provide more information on the table structure and example data may help to get an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move SQL data from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612267/move-sql-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Comment: You need sample data and desired results.  I don't understand what you mean by "move".

Comment: Thank you @Myonara

Comment: @FerasAlSous thanks for point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update table column by using join

```
update t2
set t2.reg2=t1.reg
from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
on t2.ID2=t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (reg2)
SELECT reg
FROM table1
WHERE table2.ID2 = table1.ID;
```